# What's a database efficient way to check whether an object has one or more children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to check whether an object contains one or more children:

```
if @question.replies.count > 0 
  // do this
else
  // do that
end
```

however I'd rather not do the db lookups involved in this. Is there a nice efficient way of doing this query?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the **most** efficient, but you could do (in terms of Rails syntax): `@question.replies.limit(2)` so that at most 2 items are returned. This would make the query smaller/faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :counter_cache ( http://asciicasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column )

Answer (score 2):

If you've already loaded replies through an `include`, you can use `@question.replies.length` or `@question.replies.size` (more info [here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size)). You can also simplify your `if` statement to

```
if @question.replies.present?
```

Otherwise, you can use a `counter_cache` column, which will just maintain a column on your questions table (`replies_count`) that you can access at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have eager loaded associations, then use the `present?` method

```
class User
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :replies
end

current_user.messages.all(:include => :replies).each do |message|
  if message.replies.present?
  else
  end
end
```

If you haven't loaded the associations to memory, then use the `exists?` method.

```
current_user.messages.each do |message|
  if message.replies.exists?
  else
  end
end
```

The `exists?` call results in [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) check which returns upon finding the first matching row without incurring the cost of getting the row data back from DB.

**Note**

Other option is to use the `counter_cache` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11037997/163203) as suggested by [@dimuch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416723/dimuch). The `counter_cache` solution is efficient if you can alter your DB table structure.

Comment: Thank you - this is a great answer. It's so complete that I'd like to mark it as the right answer but @dimuch's counter_cache reference was actually the most useful. Could you namecheck his reference and I'll mark this correct - ty